# How to add a movie to unity 2d game?

Tags: video, unity-game-engine

We created a button in our main menu which shall be connected to a movie. We don't know how to put the movie into the game. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [MovieTexture](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-MovieTexture.html). Note that this differs between platforms - what is your target?

Comment: Thanks. Maybe this will help us. Our aim os to add this video into a new room, which is then connected with a button to the main menu. It tells the background story to the game.

Comment: I meant what are you going to run your game on - Desktop, iOS, Android etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to play movie to Android/iOS. You can use Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie -> http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie.html